# What are common sources of randomness in Machine Learning projects with Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, reproducible-research

Reproducibility is important. In a closed-source machine learning project I'm currently working on it is hard to achieve it. What are the parts to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setting seeds

Computers have pseudo-random number generators which are initialized with a value called the seed. For machine learning, you might need to do the following:

```
# I've heard the order here is important
import random
random.seed(0)

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(0)
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                              inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)

from keras import backend as K
K.set_session(sess)  # tell keras about the seeded session

# now import keras stuff
```

See also: [Keras FAQ: How can I obtain reproducible results using Keras during development?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development)

### sklearn

[sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split) has a `random_state` parameter.

### What to check

1. Am I loading the data in the same order every time?
2. Do I initialize the model the same way?
3. Do you use external data that might change?
4. Do you use external state that might change (e.g. `datetime.now`)?